# PHP Error when uploading more then 4 files at a strech

Tags: php, file-upload, multiple-file-upload

When I try to upload four or less than four files, it's working fine. But when I try to upload more than four files, I am getting the following error:

```
Warning: Invalid argument supplied for foreach() in C:\wamp\www\multiple-file-upload-with-php\index.php on line 16
Notice: Undefined index: files in C:\wamp\www\multiple-file-upload-with-php\index.php on line 16
```

I'm using the following HTML:

```
    <!-- Multiple file upload html form-->
    <form action="" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
        <input type="file" name="files[]" multiple="multiple" accept="image/*">
        <input type="submit" value="Upload">
    </form>
```

and PHP:

```
if(isset($_POST) and $_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] == "POST"){

$valid_formats = array("jpg", "png", "gif", "zip", "bmp");
$max_file_size = 1024*100; //100 kb
$path = "uploads/"; // Upload directory
$count = 0;

// Loop $_FILES to execute all files
foreach ($_FILES['files']['name'] as $f => $name) {     
    if ($_FILES['files']['error'][$f] == 4) {
        continue; // Skip file if any error found
    }          
    if ($_FILES['files']['error'][$f] == 0) {              
        if ($_FILES['files']['size'][$f] > $max_file_size) {
            $message[] = "$name is too large!.";
            continue; // Skip large files
        }
        elseif( ! in_array(pathinfo($name, PATHINFO_EXTENSION), $valid_formats) ){
            $message[] = "$name is not a valid format";
            continue; // Skip invalid file formats
        }
        else{ // No error found! Move uploaded files 
            if(move_uploaded_file($_FILES["files"]["tmp_name"][$f], $path.$name)) {
                $count++; // Number of successfully uploaded files
            }
        }
    }
}
}
```

What might be the problem?

Comment: http://php.net/manual/en/ini.core.php#ini.max-file-uploads check your php.ini

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Edit your php.ini file and do the changes as shown below :

```
max_file_uploads=20
```

Refer this : http://php.net/manual/en/ini.core.php

Also change these things :

```
upload_max_filesize = 100M
post_max_size = 100M
```

Cheers :-)

Comment: `max_file_uploads` is also important ;)

Comment: Yes ofcourse, Sorry I missed to mention it. Thank you Raphael

Comment: Doesn't look like an answer, you don't know whether he has this config already or not. Looks more like a wild guess.

Comment: changed "post_max_size = 100M" in php.ini and it really works like a charm :). Thank you once again

Comment: You are welcome :-), Chilion: yes it was a not a wild guess, I had faced this issue before, Strange but true. Once I change the post_max_size. I worked.

Comment: Thank you Chilion, One doubt is going on my mind that "PHP will check the post_max_size value before executing the uploading PHP file?". I researched about it, Couldn't get anything useful :-(